# How to pick points inside a circle in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es-2.0, cgal

For a point cloud, I am trying to pick points inside a circle(which represent the mouse's position), just like [image: this].

Currently I do this work by:

1. cast a ray from the circle center.
2. calculate the closest point to the ray.
3. calculate the distance between closest point and other points in this point cloud, and then select those points which distance < r（r represent the radius of the circle）.

But I found some problem with this method,

1. sometimes the closest point to the ray is not what I want, since a point cloud have two side, front side and back side. Just like the following image, what I expect is the blue one, but the closest point to the ray might be the red one.
2. this method is so slow.
   [image]

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Another way of doing this is by checking if points are inside a cone. The tip of the cone is the position of the camera and angle needs to be calculated based on distance to object surface

Comment: To prefer closer points, you have to evaluate the distance from eye. You can get it projecting the found point onto your pick ray. (That's usually a dot product.) You should also check whether the found point is not in front of near clip plane. Otherwise, you may hit points in your back. Btw. One opportunity to save some cycles is to compare the square of distances. The square root usually needed to get the length of a vector (or the distance between two points) might be an expensive op. but it doesn't contribute for the comparison of two lengths (or distances).

Comment: _this method is so slow._ Processing all points of a point cloud with such algorithm might cause a significant impact. There is not much you can do with your algorithm. To earn performance, you have to re-organize your point cloud applying some kind of partitioning which can be used in [branch and bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound).